# T-SQL Stored procedure CASE issue

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong here?

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[GetUserEULASelection] (@username VARCHAR(150))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result VARCHAR(250);

    SELECT @result = a.NAME
    FROM licmn_license_users_accounts_c ua
    JOIN accounts a ON a.id = ua.licmn_license_users_accountsaccounts_ida
    JOIN licmn_license_users lu ON lu.id = licmn_license_users_accountslicmn_license_users_idb
    WHERE lu.username = @username;

    CASE 
        WHEN @result IS NOT NULL
            THEN SELECT @result AS 'name'
        END
    CASE 
        WHEN @result IS NULL
            THEN SELECT '0' AS 'name'
    END
END
```

I am new to T-SQL (I am porting MySQL Procedures to MSSQL)

The problem is that the case statement causes compilation errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem (as noted in other answers) is that you cannot use a case statement like this, an if would be more appropriate.

However, you could get rid of that conditional statement altogether, along with the local variable:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[GetUserEULASelection] (@username VARCHAR(150))
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT COALESCE(a.NAME, '0') AS Name
    FROM licmn_license_users_accounts_c ua
    JOIN accounts a ON a.id = ua.licmn_license_users_accountsaccounts_ida
    JOIN licmn_license_users lu ON lu.id = licmn_license_users_accountslicmn_license_users_idb
    WHERE lu.username = @username;    

END
```

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong is you're using CASE incorrectly. You're mixing it up with an IF in that context

So you should properly do:

```
IF @result IS NOT NULL
   SELECT @result AS name
ELSE
    SELECT '0' AS name
```

If you want to use CASE you should do it in the query:

```
 SELECT CASE 
       WHEN a.NAME IS NULL THEN '0'
       ELSE a.NAME 
     END as Name
    FROM licmn_license_users_accounts_c ua
    JOIN accounts a ON a.id = ua.licmn_license_users_accountsaccounts_ida
    JOIN licmn_license_users lu ON lu.id = licmn_license_users_accountslicmn_license_users_idb
    WHERE lu.username = @username;
```

Answer (score 2):

`case` is not a control flow construct.  `if` is for control flow.  I would suggest replacing the `case` with a single `select`:

```
SELECT coalesce(@result, '0') AS name;
```

Also, only use single quotes for string and date constants.  You are using single quotes for a column alias.  Although supported, this often leads to other problems in code.

EDIT:

You can replace the whole body of the stored procedure with:

```
SELECT coalesce(max(a.NAME), '0')
FROM licmn_license_users_accounts_c ua JOIN
     accounts a
     ON a.id = ua.licmn_license_users_accountsaccounts_ida JOIN
     licmn_license_users lu
     ON lu.id = licmn_license_users_accountslicmn_license_users_idb
WHERE lu.username = @username;
```

Note the use of `max()`.  This guarantees that a row will be returned even when there are no matches.

Answer (score 1):

Use IF condition, CASE expression is only for SELECT statements

Answer (score 1):

Case is used in sql. You need to use if instead outside of query.